# react-native-calendars ExpandableCalendar not worknig propely with RTL in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-calendars

I'm trying to use ExpandableCalendar from  https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars

my App set to RTL `ReactNative.I18nManager.allowRTL(true); ReactNative.I18nManager.forceRTL(true);`

when the calendar is expanded and I'm trying to change the month it doesn't show new dates of next month or prev month, it's just showing name of the month that different from the header month.

however setting RTL to false fixes the problem. is there some solution without setting RTL to false?

image after changing month by swiping right/left or by clicking on arrows to change month:

[image]

Comment: Can you share ur code in repo or snack?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with `react-native-calendars`. It is not able to render the child components (the dates) properly or is just ignoring it when `ReactNative.I18nManager.allowRTL(true);`.

For now, the temporary solution is to change the flex-direction to `row-reverse` and rendering the arrows in the opposite direction:

```
<Calendar theme={'stylesheet.calendar.main': {
                        week: {
                          marginTop: 7,
                          marginBottom: 7,
                          flexDirection: isRTL ? 'row-reverse' : 'row',
                          justifyContent: 'space-around'
                        }
                       },
                  'stylesheet.calendar.header': {
                        header: {
                           flexDirection: isRTL ? 'row-reverse' : 'row',
                          justifyContent: 'space-between',
                          paddingLeft: 10,
                          paddingRight: 10,
                          alignItems: 'center',
                          height: 45
                        },
                        week: {
                          marginTop: 7,
                           flexDirection: isRTL ? 'row-reverse' : 'row',
                          justifyContent: 'space-around'
                        }}
                      }}
            renderArrow={direction => <Icon type="ionicon"
                                            name={direction === 'left'
                                               ? (isRTL ? 'arrow-forward' : 'arrow-back')
                                               : (isRTL ? 'arrow-back' : 'arrow-forward')}
                                               />}
    />
```